NodeJS Heroku delaying daily restart
I'm working on an application that uses Heroku as a cron scheduler in Node (Except instead of cron add-ons, it is using Node Cron). In short, every 20 minutes it'll reach out to a third party service to ask if any emails need forwarded, and if so, to forward them. Additionally, at the 30th of every hour, it'll generate some reports, as needed.
I have been made aware that sometimes these batches get cutoff (emails get "stuck", etc), from which I strongly suspect the 24 hour window to be at play. I checked out the documentation for Heroku, and noticed that there are two ways restarts can be delayed:

Manual restarts (heroku ps:restart)
Releases (deploys or changing config vars)

Does anybody happen to know if killing the application after a cron task would also delay the 24 hour window (EG, the infamous process.exit(0))? Or is it strictly releases / manual restarts?
Long term, I would like to change the pattern of this service to accommodate restarting every ~24 hours. But if I can add a patch in now, that would be great too!
